# I am getting a Fatal Exception: Main

Tags: java, android, null

I am very new to android and just learning on the fly mostly from tutorial videos.  I am having an issue where I am getting a fatal exception when I try to run the app.  I believe the portion of the code generating the error is below, I have a char array of letters that I am trying to scramble and then set the text of certain buttons to those letters (i.e. letter1A.setText(scrambleLettersChar[0]).  I did the same thing above this portion of the code and it worked just fine.   TIA.

```
char[] solutionLetters = {letter1, letter2, letter3, letter4, letter5, letter6, letter7, letter8, letter9, letter10, letter11, letter12};

                for (int i = 0; i < solutionLetters.length; i++) {
                    int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * solutionLetters.length);
                    char temp = solutionLetters[i];
                    solutionLetters[i] = solutionLetters[randomIndex];
                    solutionLetters[randomIndex] = temp;

                }
                String scrambleLettersString = new String(solutionLetters);
                scrambleLettersChar = scrambleLettersString.toCharArray();

                letter1A.setText(scrambleLettersChar[0]);


            }
```

Comment: `I believe the portion ...` - instead of guessing, just read the stacktrace from your crash, which shall point to exact reason of the crash and culprit in your code

Comment: You could also include the stacktrace in your question so don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`solutionLetters` is the reason. Your trying to access an item in the `solutionLetters` array which is out of bounds.

Use `randInt(0, solutionLetters.size()-1` instead of `(int) (Math.random() * solutionLetters.length);`

Rough code, in future please post your stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The error in this line :

```
 letter1A.setText(scrambleLettersChar[0]);
```

Change this to :

```
 letter1A.setText(scrambleLettersChar[0] + "");
```

> The reason is when you invoke setText... setText(int resId) is invoked
>   instead of setText(CharSequence)

Comment: That worked and makes sense, thanks for the help.

Comment: If it helped, please mark the answer as correct. it may help others.